# Does knowing a group is abelian ever make any relation "weaker"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to solve a homework problem in an algebra class and I think I've solved it, although I'm not sure if my argument is valid. The problem is as follows:

> Compute the order $|G|\in\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ of the group $G$ with the presentation $$G=\langle x,y\ |\ x^2y=e, xy^3=e\rangle$$

My attempted solution is as follows:

The second relation gives $e=xy^3=x^{-1}(x^2y)y^2$. Furthermore, the first relation gives $x^{-1}(x^2y)y^2=x^{-1}y^2$, which proves that $x^{-1}y^2=e$, or equivalently that $x=y^2$. Plugging that into both relations, we get that the only restriction is that $y^5=e$. Since $x$ can be generated by $y$ we can discard $x$ and observe that this is a cyclic group of order $5$.

The part I'm not really sure about is the one where I discard the original relations and replace them by the fact that $x=y^2$ combined with the fact that $y^5=e$. Are there any restrictions that I am missing this way?

Comment: In general, in a group presentation, if you can express one generator $x$ as a word $w$ in the remaining generators (and inverses), then you can substitute $w$ for $x$ in all other group relations, and then delete $x$ and the relation $x=w$ from the presentation. This is one of the *Tietze transformations*, and the fact that this results in a group isomorphic to the original group is a standard result (and not very hard to prove).

Answer (score 4):

A clean way to prove the existence of an isomorphism between groups defined by presentations is to define homomorphisms both ways and prove that they're inverses. To define a homomorphism out of a group defined by a presentation, just say where it takes the generators and prove that the relations are all respected. (More precisely, first define a homomorphism from the free group on the generators, and then show it takes the relators to the identity, so it descends to the quotient group.)

Let $H=\left<z\mid z^5=e\right>$. We can define $f\colon G\to H$ and $g\colon H\to G$ by setting $f(x) = z^2$, $f(y) = z$, and $g(z) = y$, and checking that 
\begin{align*}
f(x^2y) &= f(xy^3) = e,\\
g(z^5) &= e,\\
f\circ g(z) &= z,\\
g\circ f(x) &= x,\\
g\circ f(y) &= y.
\end{align*}
Thus $f$ and $g$ define inverse homomorphisms.